# Fetch all subtypes when findBy a parent property - JPA inheritance with joined strategy

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, inheritance

I have the inheritance hierarchy as follows.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User{
private Long id;
private String username;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "patient")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "user_id")
public class Patient extends User{
//some patient specific fields
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "member")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "user_id")
public class Member extends User{
//some provider specific fields
}
```

Both the patient and member tables have the user_id column as the foreign key as below.

Patient table
[image]

Member Table
[image]

So the user can be both patient and provider as per our design. Now I want to fetch the user with both patient and provider details. How can I do that?

When I tried, it is just fetching only the members

```
 var users = userRepository.getByUsername(username);

 @Query(value = "from User u where u.username = :username")
 List<User> getByUsername(String username);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are after as Java inheritance won't let a single object be both a Member and Patient at the same time. You cannot have more than one member/Patient row pointing at the same user. I don't understand how you can have two member rows referencing the same User_Id value - it should be an error. Member isn't its own entity separate from user - user_id should 'be' its unique identifier when inheritance is involved. If you want to apply them like a role, you should be using a relationship between them, not java object inheritance.

Comment: @chris Ok. Consider there is a single row on the member table. Is it possible to fetch both the patient and member by a single query

Comment: I don't understand your java model again. You cannot have an instance that is both a Patient and a Member at the same time. When you call insert with PatientX, what do you expect will happen when there is already a MemberX using that same user 'X' id? If you want to be able to make a user a 'member' or a 'patient' you need to have a single User java class that can have a member or patient instance/role created and added to it. Two separate One to One mappings. A Member data instance/role is associated with(to) a User, not a Member is a User.